# resize a imagem with 2 div fixed (header and footer)

Tags: css, html, resize, fixed

My problem:
[image]

What I need do:

[image]

Someone can help me? Url: thiago **** solano (.) com (.) br/index2.php/ (retire ****)

Very thanks!

Comment: your link doesnt work. use a URL shortener that is painful what you wrote

Answer (score 0):

Change the default width and height of PrettyPhoto:

```
pp_settings = jQuery.extend({
...
default_width: 500,
default_height: 344,
...
```

Comment: change to %? Because if I set a default value, not be resized on all screens

Comment: thats how pretty photo works, if you want a fullscreen implementation that resizes automatically you would either need to write it yourself or use something more simple like http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Answer (score 0):

You could set the width of the image to something like 800px for a fixed width or, probably better, 80% for a somewhat dynamic width.

Then, put the image inside a `div` and set the left and right margin to auto

```
divImgContainer{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see your link.

What I would do anyways would be to target that img that ( maybe with a class ) like this:

```
<img class="imgClass" src="myImage.jpg" />


.imgClass{
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```